# User defined function not working with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, user-defined-functions

I was learning Python Pandas, so wrote a little code to experiment with user defined functions used with `agg`, as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

def combine_cities(series):
       return reduce(lambda x, y: x + ', ' + y, series)

data = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['Russia','USA','China','USA','China'],
                    'City':['Moscow','Boston','Wuhan','New York','Beijing']})
a = data.groupby('Country').agg(combine_cities)
print(a)
```

However, I get the following error. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in agg_series(self, obj, func)
    662         try:
--> 663             return self._aggregate_series_fast(obj, func)
    664         except Exception:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in _aggregate_series_fast(self, obj, func)
    680         grouper = reduction.SeriesGrouper(obj, func, group_index, ngroups, dummy)
--> 681         result, counts = grouper.get_result()
    682         return result, counts

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result()

pandas\_libs\reduction.pyx in pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result()

....
```

Comment: I tried it and it works... (python 3.8, pandas 1.0.0, ran in Spyder)

Comment: Strange. I ran it in my Jupyter note but it fails.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python3. I now realize I had to add from functools import reduce, as reduce was removed from Python3,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the error was occuring was that Python3 has removed the reduce function. Therefore, I had to add the following to make it work.

```
from functools import reduce
```